Looking for Sci-fi book about frozen capsule which contains alien form in frozen state which escape once human enter the egg-shape capsule
The book is about a space crew which discovers a frozen capsule in deep space which contains alien life which escapes from the capsule and threats life on space ship and nearby planet. The alien life can change its shape.
The story unfolds as such:
Once the capsule is discovered, a space crew sends one member to investigate. While a human is in the capsule, the alien form despite being in deep frozen state detects the presence of a human, wakes up and attacks. Then the alien form invades the spaceship. I do not remember in details, but the alien form multiplies by converting the human host into their own kind. Later, alien form manages to escape the spaceship to land on nearby planet (not Earth) where it continues its expansion. Alien form poses rapid movements; thus humans have hard time to resist. Moreover, alien form develops some kind of ugly flaps/soft wings in its body. That is basically all details that I can recollect.

You already asked this question no?  if you've remembered additional details you should edit them into that question instead of reposting it.

David, Thank you for the feedback. See, I did added an additional details as initial post which was somewhat limited and experienced member left the comments about the lack of the details. However, as I'm not aware how exactly this site operates and because after two days no one suggested anything after fresh details, I've assumed that fresh comments in old post had no effect; thus I proceeded with new post which provides noticeably more details about the sci-fi book I'm trying to locate.

We've added the extra details into your original question. Hopefully this will be enough to trigger someone's memory.
